# Multiple docker-compose file with different context path

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have 2 docker-compose files that I need to run together, the locations of the files are like

**/home/project1/docker-compose.yml**

and

**/home/project2/docker-compose.yml**

so clearly both the services should have different contextpath

But when I run below docker compose command

**docker-compose -f /home/project1/docker-compose.yml -f /home/project2/docker-compose.yml config**

I get to see, Both the service are getting the same context path

```
app:
    build:
      context: /home/project1
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
app2:
    build:
      context: /home/project1
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

How can I resolve this issue I want both my services to have their own project path ie.

**app service should have context path /home/project1**

and

**app2 service should have context path /home/project2**

Comment: if you use docker swarm. Yon can specify replicas

Comment: How is that going to help me here, could you please elaborate this.

Comment: did you find any solution to this?

Comment: It's an open [issue on Github](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3874), but there's a few suggestions for workarounds in the comments.

Comment: @Tim I have posted the way I solved this issue and it is a generic one I have seen this approach being followed at large level at my current company.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They way I found could run multiple services is:

**1. First of all create images for all the services with the help of docker build command**

ex: in my case it is a java application with maven build tool, so command I used:

`mvn clean package docker:build -Denv=$ENV -DskipTests`

**2. After all the images built, create a common docker-compose file which will look like this**

```
version: '3'

services:
  service1:
    image: <service1-image>
    ports:
      - "8100:8080"
    environment:
      - TZ=Asia/Kolkata
      - MYSQL_USER=root
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=unroot
    ulimits:
      nproc: 65535
      nofile:
        soft: 65535
        hard: 65535
  service2:
    image: <service2-image>
    ports:
      - "8101:8080"
    environment:
      - TZ=Asia/Kolkata
      - MYSQL_USER=root
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=unroot
    ulimits:
      nproc: 65535
      nofile:
        soft: 65535
        hard: 65535
  service3:
    image: <service3-image>
    environment:
      - TZ=Asia/Kolkata
      - MYSQL_USER=root
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=unroot
    ulimits:
      nproc: 65535
      nofile:
        soft: 65535
        hard: 65535
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: dev
```

The way I have mentioned mysql root, password, you can also add environment variables.

**3.Then run below command to run all the services**

`docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up`

or run below command to run specific service

`docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up service1`

This is working fine for me, this will require 1 time setup but after that it will be very easy and fast.

Answer (score 5):

**Option 1**:
Use absolute paths for the contexts in both docker-compose files

**Option 2**:
Create a docker-compose.override.yml with the absolute paths:

```
version: "3"

services:
  service1:
    build:
      context: /home/project1
  service2:
    build:
      context: /home/project2
```

and include it in the docker-compose command:

```
docker-compose -f /home/project1/docker-compose.yml -f /home/project2/docker-compose.yml -f /home/docker-compose.override.yml config
```

On linux, to avoid hard-coding of the base path in the docker-compose.override.yml, you can use PWD environment variable:

```
services:
  service1:
    build:
      context: ${PWD}/project1
  service2:
    build:
      context: ${PWD}/project2
```

Comment: i believe option 1 will not work because all paths will be relative to the location of the first passed docker-compose file.

Comment: @Tim No, that's not the case. Relative paths are resolved relative to the location of the first docker-compose file, absolute paths stay as they were.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that when using multiple docker-compose files the context is taken from the location of the first file. It is explained in detail in this issue

https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3874